# UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username while trying to register the user in django

Tags: python, django

I have written following set of code in views.py of my project but when I try to register the user info as an object in the database, above mentioned error arrived

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, "authentication/index.html")

def signin(request):

    if request.method == "post":
        username = request.POST['username']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']

        user = authenticate(username = username, password=pass1)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            fname = user.first_name
            return render(request, 'authenticate/index.html', {'fname' : fname})
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Bad credentials')
            return redirect('home')

    return render(request, "authentication/signin.html")

def signup(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        # username = request.POST.get('username')
        username = request.POST['username']
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        email = request.POST['email']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)   ## Error is coming in this line ##
        myuser.firstname = fname
        myuser.lastname = lname

        myuser.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Your account has been succesfully created.')

        return redirect('/signin')
        


    return render(request, "authentication/signup.html")

def signout(request):
    pass
```

I am trying to make user login system and following error has arrived in views.py of my app. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6uXq.png)

Comment: Before creating the user, your signup url should verify that the username does not already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the `username` already exists in the database as you haven't used django forms so maybe the validation isn't done correctly with your manually defined html fields.

Also `create_user()` method doesn't require `save()` method to be called for updating the fields, the thing you can do is `save(commit=False)` but I think you can directly use `create()` method.

You should first check whether the user with username already exists in the database or not.

Use this view:

```py
from django.contrib import messages
def signup(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
     
        username = request.POST['username']
        try:       
            user_exist_or_not=User.objects.get(username=username)  
            messages.error(request,"user already exists")
            return redirect("some_error_page")
        
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            print("user does not exist")
       
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        email = request.POST['email']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

        myuser = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, password=pass1,first_name=fname,last_name=lname)

        messages.success(request, 'Your account has been succesfully created.')

        return redirect('/signin')
        


    return render(request, "authentication/signup.html")
```